# Smallest number $m$ with $gnu(m)=2017\ $?

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

$gnu(n)$ denotes the number of groups of order $n$ upto isomorphy.

$moa(n)$ denotes the smallest number $m$ with $gnu(m)=n$

$$m=259,083,319,343,897,905=5\cdot 2011\cdot 24133\cdot 1067692187$$

satisfies $gnu(m)=2017$, so $moa(2017)$ exists, but this number $m$ should be far away from $moa(2017)$.

The numbers $m\le 2,047$ and the cubefree numbers $m\le 50,000$ do not satisfy $gnu(m)=2017$.

> Who knows a better upper bound for $moa(2017)\ $?
>
> A sensible upper bound would, for example, be the smallest cubefree number $m$ with $gnu(m)=2017$.

Comment: $2017$ is suspiciously close to the current year ... is this a contest problem?

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, but the reason, why I chose this number.

Comment: @Peter by the way what is the smallest $n$ with $moa(n)$ unknown?

Comment: According to https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf it is $moa(31)\le 11774$, but according to my lb-function, we have $moa(31)=11774$. The next is $moa(33)\le 163293$.

Comment: The two candidates below $50,000$ are : [ $29282, 43923$ ]